# Does playing a 1080x1440 (16:9 aspect ratio) video in a 720x1600 phone decreases the quality a bit?

Tags: screen-resolution

If I play a youtube video in 1080p quality, that's actually 1080x1440 (16:9 aspect ratio) resolution, right?

[Realme 5 vs Redmi note 7 comparison:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bji9jFKAyEdoJopNBkqNAaAUqb975Igo/view?usp=drivesdk)
720x1600 | 1080x2340

I'm wondering if realme 5 only supports up to 720px (in height), but it supports up to 1600px (in width).

Will that decreases the quality of the video a bit compared to playing it on a Redmi Note 7 that supports up to 1080x2340?

Or I will get the same 'Full HD' quality of a 1080x1440 video on both resolution in my naked eye?

Comment: 1080p = 1920×1080